# Jquery select class from variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using Jquery to find a class by variable. So,

```
var className = "whatever";
```

*$("#container ul li") if contains element with className, do this*

How do I write the above code?

Is it

```
$("#container ul li").find("."+ className).each(function(){
console.log("I found one");
});
```

Obviously the code doesn't work

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is the `className` on the `<li>` element? If so, you could do this:

```
$('#container ul li.' + className)...
```

You're just concatenating the className into the selector string (with [the class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector)).

Or this will give you the same result.

```
$('#container ul li').filter('.' + className)...
```

Which is the similar to your `.find()` solution, but [uses `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to limit the `<li>` elements found to those with the `className`.

---

If the element with the `className` is a descendant of the `<li>` element, then [using `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) should work, or you could do:

```
$('#container ul li .' + className)...
```

...which almost looks the same as the one above, but introduces a space after `li`, which is [a descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector).

Comment: The filter solution works. Thanks for clarifying that find() is used to find descendants!