# pass div class as jquery aurgument and clear all elements under that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to create a common jquery function to clear all elements in a div. i'm having many pages and forms so i'm creating common function in which i'll pass the class of a div and clear it in jquery. 
the code i have tried is,

```
function ClearCntrl(cntrl){
    $('.cntrl').ajaxForm(function() {
        this.reset();
    });
}
```

and the button on which i want to clear elements in div is

```
<input type="submit" name="name-submit" value="submit" id="name-submit" class="btn btn-info"  onclick = "ClearCntrl(adds)">
```

adds is the class of a div i want to clear

Comment: `$('.cntrl')` this isn't using your variable, it is a static value. Also your onclick isn't setup right unless `adds` is a variable, ie strings still need quotes when using them in inline js attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery select class from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951302/jquery-select-class-from-variable)

Comment: Check out [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

What your current function is doing is calling ajaxForm() on all elements with **.cntrl** class every time.

If you want to have generic function, change it into:

```
function ClearCntrl(cntrl){
    $(cntrl).ajaxForm(function() {
        this.reset();
    });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
ClearCntrl('.adds');
```

Comment: It actually gets to .ajaxForm function but throws an error because this.reset is not a function.

Comment: I am not familiar with ajaxForm plugin so I can't help you with that part

Comment: Need Ad jquery reset plugin , but it never gets into Ajax form function